# how paypal library can be used in codenameone?

Tags: paypal, codenameone

I want to add payment feature in codenameone app and I am planning to use paypal. 
How can I implement it in my app?
https://www.paypal.com/

Answer (score 1):

PayPal has an SDK that you can probably integrate directly into the Codename One application by following the tutorial on integrating 3rd party SDK's https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_integrating_3rd_party_native_sdks